# How can i Extract all the links with theire names from a website using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I made a simple program to fetch links in mp3 format from the site, but when I extract the links, they come to me in the form of HTML codes, but I want them in the form of links only with their names.

This code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for u in soup.find_all("a"):
    print("Downloading {}".format(u))
```

```
<a href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/romantic/">
<noscript><img alt="" src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Romantic.jpg"/></noscript><img alt="" class="lazyload" data-src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Romantic.jpg" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%20210%20140%22%3E%3C/svg%3E"/>
<div class="tag-name">Romantic</div>
<span class="tag-count">68</span>
</a>
<a href="https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27010/">Dark Forest</a>
<a class="artist-name" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/?keyword=McFunkypants&amp;artist" rel="nofollow">McFunkypants</a>
<a href="https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/" rel="license" target="_blank" title="This track is licensed under Creative Commons CC0 1.0 Universal (CC0 1.0) Public Domain Dedication"></a>
<a class="download-button track-download" href="https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27010/">Download</a>
<a class="tag-cloud-link-names" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/games/">Games</a>
<a class="tag-cloud-link-names" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/suspense/">Suspense</a>
<a class="tag-cloud-link-names" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/cinematic/">Cinematic</a>
<a href="https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27957/">Peacful water stream in forest</a>
<a class="artist-name" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/?keyword=Chosic&amp;artist" rel="nofollow">Chosic</a>
<a href="https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/" rel="license" target="_blank" title="This track is licensed under Creative Commons CC0 1.0 Universal (CC0 1.0) Public Domain Dedication"></a>
<a class="download-button track-download" href="https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27957/">Download</a>
<a class="tag-cloud-link-names" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/nature/">Nature</a>
<a href="https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/25499/">A really dark alley</a>
<a class="artist-name" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/?keyword=Loyalty Freak Music&amp;artist" rel="nofollow">Loyalty Freak Music</a>
<a href="https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/" rel="license" target="_blank" title="This track is licensed under Creative Commons CC0 1.0 Universal (CC0 1.0) Public Domain Dedication"></a>
<a class="download-button track-download" href="https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/25499/">Download</a>
<a class="tag-cloud-link-names" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/horror/">Horror</a>
<a href="https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/25909/">Handel , Largo (from ‘Xerxes’)</a>
<a class="artist-name" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/?keyword=The London Baroque Orchestra&amp;artist" rel="nofollow">The London Baroque Orchestra</a>
<a href="https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/mark/1.0/" rel="license" target="_blank" title="This track is licensed under Creative Commons Public Domain Mark 1.0"></a>
<a class="download-button track-download" href="https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/25909/">Download</a>
<a class="tag-cloud-link-names" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/cinematic/">Cinematic</a>
<a class="tag-cloud-link-names" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/sad/">Sad</a>
<a class="tag-cloud-link-names" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/classical/">Classical</a>
<a class="link-as-button" href="?attribution=no">View all public domain tracks →</a>
<a href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/piano/">
<noscript><img alt="" src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Piano.jpg"/></noscript><img alt="" class="lazyload" data-src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Piano.jpg" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%20210%20140%22%3E%3C/svg%3E"/>
<div class="tag-name">Piano</div>
<span class="tag-count">122</span>
</a>
<a href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/nature/">
<noscript><img alt="" src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Nature.jpg"/></noscript><img alt="" class="lazyload" data-src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Nature.jpg" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%20210%20140%22%3E%3C/svg%3E"/>
<div class="tag-name">Nature</div>
<span class="tag-count">25</span>
</a>
<a href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/beats/">
<noscript><img alt="" src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Beats.jpg"/></noscript><img alt="" class="lazyload" data-src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Beats.jpg" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%20210%20140%22%3E%3C/svg%3E"/>
<div class="tag-name">Beats</div>
<span class="tag-count">85</span>
</a>
<a href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/lofi/">
<noscript><img alt="" src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Lofi.jpg"/></noscript><img alt="" class="lazyload" data-src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Lofi.jpg" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%20210%20140%22%3E%3C/svg%3E"/>
<div class="tag-name">Lofi</div>
<span class="tag-count">40</span>
</a>
<a href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/guitar/">
<noscript><img alt="" src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Guitar.jpg"/></noscript><img alt="" class="lazyload" data-src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Guitar.jpg" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%20210%20140%22%3E%3C/svg%3E"/>
<div class="tag-name">Guitar</div>
<span class="tag-count">97</span>
</a>
<a href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/games/">
<noscript><img alt="" src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Games.jpg"/></noscript><img alt="" class="lazyload" data-src="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/FreeMusicTagsImages/small/Games.jpg" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%20210%20140%22%3E%3C/svg%3E"/>
<div class="tag-name">Games</div>
<span class="tag-count">142</span>
</a>
<a aria-label="Action" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/action/" style="font-size: 22pt">Action</a>
<a aria-label="Angry" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/angry/" style="font-size: 22pt">Angry</a>
<a aria-label="Bright" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/bright/" style="font-size: 22pt">Bright</a>
<a aria-label="Calm" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/calm/" style="font-size: 22pt">Calm</a>
<a aria-label="Cute" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/cute/" style="font-size: 22pt">Cute</a>
<a aria-label="Dark" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/dark/" style="font-size: 22pt">Dark</a>
<a aria-label="Dramatic" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/dramatic/" style="font-size: 22pt">Dramatic</a>
<a aria-label="Energetic" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/energetic/" style="font-size: 22pt">Energetic</a>
<a aria-label="Epic" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/epic/" style="font-size: 22pt">Epic</a>
<a aria-label="Fast" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/fast/" style="font-size: 22pt">Fast</a>
<a aria-label="Funny" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/funny/" style="font-size: 22pt">Funny</a>
<a aria-label="Happy" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/happy/" style="font-size: 22pt">Happy</a>
<a aria-label="Horror" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/horror/" style="font-size: 22pt">Horror</a>
<a aria-label="Motivational" class="tag-cloud-link tag-link-1896 tag-link-position-38" href="https://www.chosic.com/free-music/motivational/" style="font-size: 22pt">Motivational</a>
```

How can I extract all the links from the tag name inside HTML web page in the format mp3 with their names?

Such as:

```
0- Happy Clappy
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/24390/
1- Sweet Dreams
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/26757/
2- Inspiring Optimistic Upbeat Energetic Guitar Rhythm
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27120/
3- White Petals
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27279/
4- A Christmas adventure (Part 2)
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/28675/
5- Circus Theme (Entry of the Gladiators) – Strings Version
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/28668/
6- It feels good to be alive too
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/28670/
7- You’re The Champion
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/28700/
8- Dark Forest
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27010/
9- Peacful water stream in forest
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27957/
10- A really dark alley
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/25499/
11- Handel , Largo (from ‘Xerxes’)
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/25909/
```

Any solution possible?

Comment: A Stack Overflow question should be about a specific problem. Don't just give us your input and intended output -- give us code that demonstrates a specific problem you encountered while writing a program to transform that input to that output. (And if a shorter subset of input and output suffices to demonstrate that problem, then only the shorter subset should be used; the goal of a [mre] is to be _the shortest possible thing_ that lets others reproduce and test fixes to a specific issue when run without changes).

Comment: To put it a bit more broadly: Stack Overflow is a Q&A knowledgebase, not a code-writing service.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I understand you, but I extracted the required data. I just asked to modify it so that it becomes the form that is in the following example and thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'trackF-title-inside'})

s = ''
for i, link in enumerate(data):
    s = s + str(i) + '- ' + str(link.find('a').text) + '\n\t' + str(link.find('a', href=True)['href']) + '\n'
    
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
f.close()
```

**Outputs:**

```
0- Happy Clappy
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/24390/
1- Sweet Dreams
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/26757/
2- Inspiring Optimistic Upbeat Energetic Guitar Rhythm
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27120/
3- White Petals
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27279/
4- A Christmas adventure (Part 2)
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/28675/
5- Circus Theme (Entry of the Gladiators) – Strings Version
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/28668/
6- It feels good to be alive too
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/28670/
7- You’re The Champion
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/28700/
8- Dark Forest
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27010/
9- Peacful water stream in forest
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/27957/
10- A really dark alley
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/25499/
11- Handel , Largo (from ‘Xerxes’)
    https://www.chosic.com/download-audio/25909/
```

**Example file:**
[image]

---

**Or:**

Maybe this is what you require:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'track-info track'})

for i, element in enumerate(data):
    for link in element.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'waveform before'}):
        print(str(i) + '- ' + element.find('a').text)
        print('\t' + link['data-url'])
```

**Outputs:**

```
0- Happy Clappy
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/John_Bartmann_-_09_-_Happy_Clappy-1.mp3
1- Sweet Dreams
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/batchbug-sweet-dreams.mp3
2- Inspiring Optimistic Upbeat Energetic Guitar Rhythm
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/fm-freemusic-inspiring-optimistic-upbeat-energetic-guitar-rhythm.mp3
3- White Petals
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/keys-of-moon-white-petals.mp3
4- A Christmas adventure (Part 2)
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/TRG_Banks_-_09_-_A_Christmas_adventure_Part_2.mp3
5- Circus Theme (Entry of the Gladiators) – Strings Version
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Circus-Theme-Entry-of-the-Gladiators-Strings-Version.mp3
6- It feels good to be alive too
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Loyalty_Freak_Music_-_04_-_It_feels_good_to_be_alive_too.mp3
7- You’re The Champion
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Youre-The-Champion.mp3
8- Dark Forest
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/dark-forest.mp3
9- Peacful water stream in forest
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/kvgarlic__largestreamoverloginforestmarch.mp3
10- A really dark alley
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Loyalty_Freak_Music_-_07_-_A_really_dark_alley.mp3
11- Handel , Largo (from ‘Xerxes’)
    https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Hndel-Xerxes-HWV-40.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you've asked!

I'm not exactly sure what data you want since the example output you provided doesn't match the data on the site. But of course you can tweak the parsing logic here to give a different output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

required_data = []
count = 0

for x in soup.find_all('a'):
    if x.has_attr('href'):
        count += 1
        description = x.text.strip()
        url = x['href']
        required_data.append((count, description, url))

print(required_data)
```

Comment: There is a problem specifying the type of links. This code only comes with unformatted links. You are close to the solution

Comment: The following data in the example is just an example to illustrate the idea